# Dreamweaver CC CS6 will not install the extension emmet

Tags: installation, adobe, dreamweaver, emmet

I am having trouble installing the emmet  extension into Dreamweaver CC CS6. It keeps telling me that I need Dreamweaver version 11.0 or greater, and I have version 12.2... I have also tried to install the Adobe Exchange extension, just to see if another would work and it comes back with a message saying I need fireworks 12.0 or greater and I have 12.0.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver CC Emmet installation: Double-clicking the .zxp-file doesn't work.

**Try this:**

- Open Dreamweaver CC
- Select Window > Manage Extensions... (Extension Manager CC starts)
- Press Ctrl+O ;)
- Select Emmet.zxp
- Ignore Warnings
- Be happy